# Do Stata's lasso commands automatically standardize dummy variables?

Tags: stata, lasso-regression, standardization

stata's command lasso automatically standardizes independent variables.
It seems to automatically standardize dummy variables as well.
Is this right? then, is there a way to do lasso without standardizing the dummy variables?

lasso dependent variable independent variable